# Consulta técnica para encontrar una variable en visual basic

Tags: vb.net, asp

Me encuentro revisando un código escrito en asp con visual basic y tengo una duda, creo que algo técnico.

Entiendo que cuando uno crea un boton, input o campo escondido siempre van con un formato, ejemplos:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NotaVentaTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

o

```
<asp:Button ID="NotaVentaButton" runat="server" Text="Abrir" />
```

El caso es que en mi código Ventas.aspx.vb tengo una variable que es **Me.Cod_Bodega** y lo que tengo entendido, de lo básico que conozco de este lenguaje, es que todas las variables que empiezan con **Me** provienen de mi archivo **Venta.aspx** vendría a ser el id de una variable. Estoy en lo correcto?

Por qué pregunto esto:

Tengo una función que dentro de esta lo primero que dice es

```
Dim Bodega = Me.Cod_Bodega
```

y este Me.Cod_Bodega viene con un valor 5 que necesito cambiar, pero no logro ver de dónde lo trae.

Si alguien me pudiera aclarar esta duda se lo agradecería.

Encontré este código, pero no se si tiene que ver:

```
ReadOnly Property Venta As Venta
        Get
            Return CType(Me.Page, Venta)
        End Get
End Property

ReadOnly Property Cod_Bodega As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.Venta.Cod_Bodega     ''todo: Cod_Bodega corregir
        End Get
End Property
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Me**

El **Me** palabra clave proporciona una manera de hacer referencia a la instancia específica de una clase o estructura en la que se está ejecutando el código. Me se comporta como una variable de objeto o una variable de estructura que hace referencia a la instancia actual. Uso de Me es especialmente útil para pasar información sobre la instancia en ejecución de una clase o estructura a un procedimiento de otra clase, estructura o módulo.

En tu caso, el **Me** está haciendo referencia a una propiedad. Si deseas acceder al Valor de un objeto, por ejemplo un textbox solamente tienes que escribir el Id del objeto y su sobrecarga. NotaVentaTextBox.text

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/me-my-mybase-and-myclass

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, después me puse a buscar hacia donde hacía referencia y encontré el dato

Comment: Como dato extra,  si en el código no sabes donde fue declarada la variable puedes darle clic derecho sobre ella y seleccionar en la opción Go To Definition y te llevara a la declaración de la misma.